# Which library is better for offline support: redux-offline or react-native-offline?

Tags: react-native, mobile, redux, react-redux, redux-persist

Need suggestion on which library to use for a large react native mobile app using redux ? **redux-offline** or **react-native-offline** ?

I need to regularly check connection status, render view depending on the connection status, add actions to queue when offline and run them when online, cancel actions if some contradiction is there, and persist/rehydrate data offline.

Comment: I would suggest redux-offline.

Answer (score 4):

I am using `redux-offline` in my `react-native` project, it works just great. The feature that you are looking for all are presents like

1. It regularly checks for connection status
2. Add `action` to `offline` anytime (online \ offline)
3. Run the action as soon as device became online (moreover, you can decide the retry interval)
4. You can write your own `discard` method to drop any action based on your business requirement.
5. It uses `redux-persist` which automatically `persist\rehydrate` data. Also, you can provide your own store mechanism.

`redux-offline` is working just great for me, Sorry, I haven't used `react-native-offline` yet so can't provide you any benchmark.

Comment: does redux-offline provide encryption for state ?

Comment: No, out-of-the-box there is no support to encrypt `state`. But if you want to encrypt `store`, you can do it using `redux-persisit`'s `transforms`.

Comment: facing an issue, commit: action is not getting triggered, any idea what could be the issue? I am using redux saga middlewear

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest going for react-native-offline.

React-native-Offline provides :

1. Easier queue handling for actions based on a regex expression or a list of actions
2. Auto Triggering the online only actions , once the network is back.
3. Your Saga looks cleaner and readable, with both online/offline cases , on a maintenance perspective.

Redux-Offline provides:

1. It basically on separate online and offline actions
2. Each action and associated rollback needs to be handled

Both provides the redux-presist with connectors of your preference.

Answer (score 1):

I have evaluated both, and for my use case I decided to go with `react-native-offline`. I liked its integration and ease of setup with redux-sagas, and it's `offlineQueue` was very convenient to have when you expect your users to conduct many operations offline.

Comment: How do you handle offline POST actions ? For example, let's say a user pressed the like button which would then make an API call to increase the no. of likes in DB and while that request was in progress the user's network got disconnected.

Comment: I’m not sure while the request is in flight, but if the users connection is lost before they make the request it gets put into the FIFO offlineQueue and when network connectivity resumes it will send post these actions in the order they were dispatched by the user